# Django CSV import in order

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

Right I have my first real problem using Django, as I'm a newbie I just cannot figure this out.

I'm using [Django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (although I'm open to other suggestions, but it maps to a model and works well). Anyhow,  I want to import the data but make sure the order is specified by the user.

This is what I have so far...

**Forms.py**

**This form gets displays to the user where they then select which column represents what field in their CSV upload.**

```
COL_CHOICES = [
    ('NONE', 'No Import'),
    ('first_name', 'First Name'),
    ('last_name', 'Last Name'),
    ('company', 'Company'),
    ('mobile', 'Mobile Number'),
    ('email', 'Email Address'),
    ]


class ConfiguratorForm(forms.Form):
    col1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
```

**Back in my view.py POST to the following...**

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfiguratorForm(data=request.POST)
        # Try and import CSV
        ContactCSVModel.import_data(data=upload.filepath, extra_fields=[
            {'value': upload.group_id, 'position': 5},
            {'value': upload.uploaded_by.id, 'position': 6}])
```

**Here is now the issue.**

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):


    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    company = CharField()
    mobile = CharField()
    group = DjangoModelField(Group)
    contact_owner = DjangoModelField(User)


    class Meta:
        delimiter = ","
        dbModel = Contact
        update = {'keys': ["mobile", "group"]}
```

As you can see above, it currently only matches first_name, last_name etc in the order they are listed above not the order the user specified.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is that me, or you declare a ConfiguratorForm by mapping the POST request data, but you don't use it ? Use the form method is_valid() to know if it is OK, else return the page with the form. If the form is valid, use its attribute "cleaned_data" that is a dict for the fields' values, and transmit the values to the constructor of your ContactCSVModel no ?

Comment: yes, I'm not using the form I kinda know how that bits going to work, just not done it yet. It's the whole transmit the values to the constructor ContactCSVModel bit I'm struggling on. I need to get form into ContactCSVModel and it's not happening from everything I have tried